# What is the problems in this code ? My code not working

Tags: reactjs

please solve the code ..
code doesn't work properly.How can I solve code please help me , not working map method .
shown this message..
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

let index = 0;


function Todo(){
  const [todostate, setTodostate] = useState({
    todo: ' ',
    todoItem:[]
  })

  const changeHandler =(e)=>{
    setTodostate({...todostate, todo: e.target.value })
  }

  const clickHandler =()=>{
    setTodostate([...todostate.todoItem, {id:index++, todoItem: todostate.todo }])
  }
  return(
    <>
       <h1>Todo List</h1>

       <input type="text" value={todostate.todo} onChange={changeHandler}  />

       <button onClick={clickHandler} >Add</button>

       <ul>
        {todostate.todoItem.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: What did you find when you googled the error?

Answer (score 1):

This line is bad in several ways:

```
setTodostate([...todostate.todoItem, {id:index++, todoItem: todostate.todo }])
```

The first time you run it, you will mutate the old state

```
{todo: ' ', todoItem:[]}
```

into this new state:

```
[[], {id:0, todoItem: ' '}]
```

Then the next time you run it, the new state will become:

```
[' ', {id:1, todoItem: undefined }]
```

and the next time:

```
[undefined, {id:2, todoItem: undefined }]
```

Et cetera.

It is difficult (if not impossible) to figure out how to fix this, since you do not say what you actually want the code to do. "please solve the code .. code doesn't work properly" is not particularly helpful. But I hope my answer at least shows you what is wrong with your code, and that it will help you figure out how to fix the issue.